# Compilation failed: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following: := ; not null default character

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex

I am facing this error:

> Compilation failed,line 3 (01:07:19)
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the
>   following: := ; not null default character

And my Procedure is:

```
create or replace procedure testing
as 
v_ID NUMBER;v_ASSIGNEE_NAME varchar2(55),v_EMAIL varchar2(55),v_PHONE NUMBER;v_FIELD varchar2(50); 
begin
select ID,ASSIGNEE_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,FIELD into 
v_ID NUMBER;v_ASSIGNEE_NAME varchar2(55),v_EMAIL varchar2(55),v_PHONE NUMBER;v_FIELD varchar2(50);
FROM ASSIGNEE;
```

Answer (score 1):

> There were couple of syntactical errors which was preventing you from compiling your code. Below snippet will help you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testing
AS
  v_ID            NUMBER;
  v_ASSIGNEE_NAME VARCHAR2(55);
  v_EMAIL         VARCHAR2(55);
  v_PHONE         NUMBER;
  v_FIELD         VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  SELECT ID,
    ASSIGNEE_NAME,
    EMAIL,
    PHONE,
    FIELD
  INTO v_ID,
    v_ASSIGNEE_NAME,
    v_EMAIL,
    v_PHONE,
    v_FIELD
  FROM ASSIGNEE;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a number of issues in this, see formatted code below.  In your declaration of variables you were separating them with a comma, this needs to be a semicolon.  Also in your into clause you had included the variable types.  The best thing you can do is to format your code so that is easier to read and debug.

```
create or replace procedure testing as 
      v_ID NUMBER;
      v_ASSIGNEE_NAME varchar2(55);
      v_EMAIL varchar2(55);
      v_PHONE NUMBER;
      v_FIELD varchar2(50); 
 begin
      select ID,ASSIGNEE_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,FIELD 
      into v_ID NUMBER, v_ASSIGNEE_NAME, v_EMAIL, v_PHONE NUMBER, v_FIELD
      FROM ASSIGNEE;
end;
```